# Defer variable expansion to subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, variable, variable-substitution

My service uses environment variables extensively for configuration (mostly because it's really easy to inject those into a Docker container).

I also have some maintenance scripts that I can run against my production environment. But since I *really* don't want my shell environment configured to talk to prod by default, I have a helper script instead that sets up the environment and then calls my maintenance script. The helper script currently looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DB_NAME=foo
export DB_HOST=foo.service.local
export DB_USERNAME=testy_testerson
export DB_PASSWORD=password
export SERVICE_API_KEY=qwertyuiop
"$@"
```

And I run it like `bin/production_env.sh scripts/maintenance_script.sh arg1 arg2`. That all works great.

One of my maintenance scripts is `dump_db.sh`, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
pg_dump --no-owner --clean --if-exists --dbname "$DB_NAME" --host "$DB_HOST" --port "$DB_PORT" --username "$DB_USER" > "db/${RAILS_ENV}-dump.$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S).sql"
```

That works great, too. But I'd like to be able to run ad-hoc commands using the configured environment without putting that logic into a script file first. e.g.,

```
bin/production_env.sh psql --username "$DB_USER" --command 'select version()'
```

The problem, of course, is that the `DB_USER` variable is expanded in my current shell, before the correct `DB_USER` variable is available.

Is there a convenient way to run ad-hoc commands like this, deferring expansion of variables until the subshell? Or is putting my ad-hoc commands into a script the easiest way?

Comment: Why don't you `source` the environment setup script? This would allow you to do whatever later. You could even set `BASH_ENV` to point to it...

Comment: Because then my shell would be setup to run maintenance scripts against our production instance by default, and that scares me. I'd MUCH prefer to have to be explicit about when I'm running against production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` on your final line, and make sure the parent shell doesn't eat the `$`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=bar
export BAR=baz
eval "$@"
```

run like so:

```
wouter@gangtai:~$ ./foo.sh echo '$BAR'
baz
```

For more information, see `help eval`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Are there any edge cases that are likely to bite me by moving from `'$@'` to `eval "$@"`?

Comment: Not really. Eval was created for just this purpose (evaluate variables in strings after defining the string). It can be a security issue in case you allow untrusted input to reach your eval; but given your premise, that's unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @Dathan This does have gotchas. `eval "$@"` is essentially equivalent to `eval "$*"` as `eval` smushes all of its arguments together. You'll need to be careful with quoting and special characters in all arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your `production_env.sh` to test for no args (or some special single arg like `-i`) and then read a single line (with `-e` to allow input editing) and execute it.  Eg change its last line to:

```
if [ $# = 0 -a -t 0 ]
then read -p 'prod> ' -e cmd
     bash -c "$cmd"
else "$@"
fi
```

Comment: That's a good one! I prefer the `eval` solution posted below, though, because it allows me to grab the entire command from my shell history and re-run easily.